# Redis - Pub/Sub Internals

Tags: database, node.js, redis, socket.io

I've written a small Socket.IO server, which works fine, I can connect to it, I can send/receive messages, so everything is working ok. Just the relevant part of the code is presented here:

```
var RedisStore = require('socket.io/lib/stores/redis');
const pub = redis.createClient('127.0.0.1', 6379);
const sub = redis.createClient('127.0.0.1', 6379);
const store = redis.createClient('127.0.0.1', 6379); 

io.configure(function() {
  io.set('store', new RedisStore({
    redisPub    : pub, 
    redisSub    : sub, 
    redisClient : store
  }));
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
 socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    pub.publish("lobby", msg);
  });


  /*
   * Subscribe to the lobby and receive messages.
   */
  var sub = redis.createClient('127.0.0.1', 6379);
  sub.subscribe("lobby");
  sub.on('message', function(channel, msg) {
    socket.send(msg);
  });
});
```

Here, I'm interested in the problem where certain client is subscribed to a different room, which is why I'm also using the sub Redis variable inside each socket connection: because each client can be subscribed to a different room and can receive messages from there. I'm not entirely sure whether the code above is ok, so please let me know if I need to do anything else than define the sub Redis connection inside the Socket.IO connection: this also means that a new Redis connection is spawned for each client connecting serving his messages from the subsribed room? I guess this is quite an overhead, so I would like to solve it anyway possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both node.js and redis are very good at handling lots of connections (thousands is no problem), so what you're doing is fine.

As a side note, you will want to look into upping your file descriptor limits if you do intend on supporting thousands of connections.

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that the following is correct: when each client connects, it spawns it's own connection to the Redis server, so there is N+3 connections to Redis server, N being the number of connected clients, and 3 is the pub,sub,store connections, right? So all the clients are using those 3 connections (actually just the pub connection) to send messages to certain rooms, while they require a separate connection for their incoming messages: because they are each subscribed to a different room. This could be further optimized to only have 1 connection per each room and send messages only

Comment: to those clients connected to it, but that that really optimize that much. Is the above comment true: can I have a global pub connection for ALL clients and does every client need a separate sub connection? Thank you

Comment: The above code shows that each connection is going to get its own sub connection, so it'd be N*2+3 connections I think. As you point out, you could dedup that by having node.js subscribe to everything and act as a message router (as opposed to a dumber message pass through). Either way should work just fine, redis is very good at handling lots of connections so if you leave it as is it'll be fine in practice as well. The decision about which is better comes down to how many connections you're going to have per node.js node.. if there's only a few, then a global connection makes sense

Comment: however if there's 200 node.js nodes and they're mostly subscribing to different streams, you should just let redis take care of it